# Android - How do I get the value out of the selected spinner object?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Im creating a spinner like so

```
List<Spinnerobject> list = verificationdata.getAreaList();
ArrayAdapter<Spinnerobject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Spinnerobject>(mactivity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
msparea.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My SpinnerObject looks like this:

```
public class Spinnerobject {
    private  int id;
    private String value;

    public Spinnerobject ( int id , String value ) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    private void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    private void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    private String getValue () {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return getValue();
    }
}
```

It holds the id and the value from my database. I am able to reference the ID of the selected item in the spinner object by using this `(int) msparea.getSelectedItemId();` but I need to get the value of the selected item in the spinner object. How do I access the Spinnerobject selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the Spinnerobject selected value?

Just call [`getSelectedItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()) and cast the result to `Spinnerobject` since you filled it with an adapter of `Spinnerobject`.

```
Spinnerobject selected = (Spinnerobject) msparea.getSelectedItem();
```